# part of my js code doesnt work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I need to take google map and marker on my page, i use code from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) but only what works is position of marker. but others commands for example zoom, title of marker etc. doesnt work. after attach the mouse on marker its write Hello world and I dont know why. Please help, thanks.

here is my code

```js
function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 48.151953, lng: 17.073795};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: uluru
        });

        var contentString = testtesttest;

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map,
            title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

```css
.mapa {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Mapy</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" class="mapa"></div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBigzZWrOz-3XuKavGo1NwskECGn8SkdCY&callback=initMap"  async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could u show more parts of your code?

Comment: @ArayniMax look now

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: testtesttest is not defined"`

Comment: @geocodezip I fix it but it always doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to put quotation marks to the content of the contentString variable

```js
function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 48.151953, lng: 17.073795};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: uluru
        });

        var contentString = 'testtesttest';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map,
            title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

```css
.mapa {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Mapy</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" class="mapa"></div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBigzZWrOz-3XuKavGo1NwskECGn8SkdCY&callback=initMap"  async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesnt work :( can be problem with api key maybe? because i dont understand, why if I go with mouse over marker, it writes Hello World! if I have not it in my code.

Comment: It works for me as it should.  http://prntscr.com/hc95u2
You could see the browser console to look for an error and show it here in case you have. @bdx

Comment: i dont understand. in console i have only favicon warning, no more. i try it open in chrome, mozila, and with incognito mode, but always it looks bad http://prntscr.com/hc98ff @LMoreno10

Comment: oh my god, im stupid idiot... i did not notice that i have bad way to my javascript, because i tried something and i forgot change the way... sorry and thanks for help

Comment: There is no problem. You're welcome :)